# Apache rewrite QUERY_STRING starts with &

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a URL starts with a "&" at the beginning of the query string.

```
www.example.com/index.htm?&parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2
```

I would like to redirect a query string that starts with a & to the same URL but without the & at the beginning.

Request

```
www.example.com/index.htm?&parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2
```

Result

```
www.example.com/index.htm?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2
```

I have already made several attempts but can't get the correct rule.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds pretty straight forward:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [R=301,L]
```

Seems to work:

https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=26758c0f-cc73-4400-a525-c540d0b8ca65

Comment: OK, now that I see your solution, it's actually pretty simple. Maybe I just had a wrong way of thinking.
It works, thanks for your help!